# Is there any way to work with sessions without locking on ASP.Net MVC site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, redis, locking

Is there any way to work with sessions **without locking** on *ASP.Net MVC* site ?

*Session lock mechanism leads many problems;*

When your site **slow down** little bit, users are start to hit "F5" on the keyboard. When they do this, requests are starting to wait each other. All those requests are **hanging** on IIS at "**RequestAcquireState**" state for session module.

If a user made a simultaneous requests this will happen. Because session module in IIS and default session provider (Or generally custom ones) **has both lock mechanism.**

See:

- [Implementing a Session-State Store Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178587(v=vs.100).aspx)
- [Session State Providers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478952.aspx)

There is locking, because your workflow can be manipulated if you are not carefully designed your process. Been hacked is way big problem for you comparing with performance issues...

But if you designed your process for *shared, semi-consistent state store*, (Or simply maybe there is no need to use) **can we remove locking situation from our way completely?**

Comment: just why to ask a question while you know the answer?

Comment: For providing an article; http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161110/posting-articles-on-stack-exchange

Comment: k, makes sense to me, by the way the info you provided are valuable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes we can remove lock from our way with "**UnlockedStateProvider**".

It designed for MVC and not implements .Net SessionStateStoreProviderBase because, IIS session module also has locking mechanism.

It is a simple ActionFilterAttribute provide state store for you via HttpContext.

It has also Redis provider so you can use safely in web farm, Azure or AWS.

Please take a look:

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnlockedStateProvider.Redis
- https://github.com/efaruk/playground/tree/master/UnlockedStateProvider

> **Note:** *Developed for advanced usage and not a replacement for any SessionStateProvider...*