# Asp.Net Mvc bundled scripts are hanging in IIS on RequestAcquireState

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have recently encountered an issue with some of the javascript requests are hanging in the RequestAcquireState inside IIS worker process request listing grid. In the application, I am bundling the scripts and style sheets, with Cdn=True, EnableOptimization=True and Compilation debug = false in the hosts config.

Now, with CDN = true, I initially thought when using the below:

```
@Scripts.RenderFormat("<script src=\"{0}\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>", "~/bundles/vendor/kendo/js")
```

The request will be made from the browser to CDN (https://www.jsdelivr.com/) in this case. However, it is hitting our host.

- So just wandering the how Scripts.RenderFormat internally works?
- Does it make a request via IIS to grab content from the CDN and then sends it to the browser?
- Is Scripts.RenderFormat tying to access a session?
- Any solution to these requests donot lock on RequestAcquireState state

  Image from the IIS is attached below:

[Click here to see IIS request log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ULiK.png)

Thanks

Comment: ASP.NET Sessions are not thread-safe means you cannot have 2 concurrent requests to the same endpoint from the same session. if you have a long-running request that depends on the session state, it will cause all other concurrent requests from this same session to block until the request finishes. This behavior is even more visible when making, for example, several AJAX requests to the server because they are all from the same session. That's one of the reasons why absolutely never use ASP.NET SessionState in my applications -> it just can't scale by design.

Comment: You could refer this similar issue: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570855/requests-hanging-on-session-module-on-iis-7-5) ,[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717430/is-there-any-way-to-work-with-sessions-without-locking-on-asp-net-mvc-site)